# Галерея товара в magento

Tags: magento

Делаю свою тему.по умолчанию стоит базовая галерея в которой при нажатии на минатюры под большой картинкой товара открывается в новом браузерном окне.единственная из стандартных галерей,которая мне подходит(нажал на миниатюру и большая картинка меняется на ту,что в миниатюре) - это галерея в теме rwd. попытался перенести.перенес,но она чего то сыпит ошибки по скриптам. может кто либо сталкивался с такой проблемой или же есть какой нить бесплатный модуль?

Answer (score 1):

рабочий бесплатный модуль https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/orbitvu-sun-product-teleporting-image-gallery.html. после некоторых корректировочных действий достиг ожедаемаого результата